# Angular: A process that involves several pages (or steps)

Tags: angular, typescript, view, sequence

I'm building a registration process that involves several pages. And the user can't access the next page (or step) if it hasn't completed the previous page. That is:

```
// this is GOOD
my-application.com/step-1
my-application.com/step-2
my-application.com/step-3

// this is BAD
my-application.com/step-2
my-application.com/step-1
my-application.com/step-3
```

How can I prevent from the user to open a page if it hasn't completed the previous page?

Comment: Store something in the browsers local storage, or if you have a concept of a user, then store where they are in the database.

You can then create a service to check if they are allowed on the page, if not redirect them to the correct one

Comment: Maintain a state of step, e.g. putting a value in a service which could be shared in you step components. On loading of each step, check it. If it does not match current step. You can either redirect user to the correct one or pop up error message.

Answer (score 1):

> Angular's Route Guard is the way to go!

1. Route Guards are used to guard against unauthorized access
2. It is used for blocking non logged in users
3. It can be used in the scenario you describe

> Please refer to this [Aligator.io](https://alligator.io/angular/route-guards/) post for better understanding!